# Firestore OrderBy and Where conflict

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have simple fetch data from my Firestore db, but i would like to paginate it with some orderring and where conditions. So i am trying to fetch data with some basic filters, but face error, in docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data described that only for range <, <=, >, >= should use orderBy and where for same field, but i need only full match (==)

node v8.12.0, express, firebase functions

```
 model.collection
        .orderBy("dateCreated", 'desc')//timeStamp
        .where('tenantId', '==', 'f8XnOVUKob5jZ29oM9u9')  
        .limit(10)
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
          res.send(snapshot);
        }).catch((error) => res.send(error));
```

got next error

```
{
    "code": "failed-precondition",
    "name": "FirebaseError"
}
```

i have results only when use where or orderBy separetly but not in same time

Comment: Please make sure the code can be run standalone. We have no idea what `startAt`, `limit`, and `req.tenantId` are in your example. Reproduce the problem on your machine with hardcoded values, and then edit those into your question.

Comment: from the code above this should work unless you are using a property that doesn't exists in your collection.

Comment: and also you need to create an index for your query, please check your console log, there should be some message in the console.

Comment: please see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing

Comment: @JuniusL. i was added indexes for my fields http://prntscr.com/o2fyoy but the query still return same error

Comment: @JuniusL. found more info here https://www.fullstackfirebase.com/cloud-firestore/indexes, thank you

Comment: @JuniusL. You might want to post that as an answer.

Comment: Ok cool, I'll do that now.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've added my answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When working with [compound queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries), you need to create an [index for your queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing). Your query fails because you didn't create indexes for

```
dateCreated
tenantId
```

Your index tab should have something similar to the following, with your indexed fields.

[image: index]

Comment: When executing a get request, you will get an error like this: `Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: The query requires an index.` and the link to create a missing index. Just follow that link.

Answer (score 1):

Also another thing

you should first use where and then use orderby

instead of this:

```js
db.collection('users').orderBy('createat','desc').where('state','!==','true')
```

you should write like this:

```js
db.collection('users').where('state','!==','true').orderBy('createat','desc')
```

I don't know what is the reason of this but that is how works for me

Answer (score 1):

You can sort data using the orderBy method. There is only one not-so-obvious limitation concerning ordering data – when you’re using a range comparison (<, <=, >, >=), you can order data only by the parameter you’re querying with. So in our case, when we fetched model released after 2021, we could only order them by release date (i.e., ascending order).

```js
$model.collection
            .where('dateCreated', '>', '27-3-2021') 
            .orderBy("dateCreated", 'desc')//timeStamp
            .limit(10)
            .get()
            .then((snapshot) => {
              res.send(snapshot);
            }).catch((error) => res.send(error));
```