# Query with limit flutter firebase firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I try to mix `where` and `orderBy` but this code doesn't work:

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> getTop10Songs() async* {
    yield* fireStore.collection('programs').where('title', isEqualTo: 'Lama').orderBy('subtitle').limit(2).snapshots();
  }
```

But if I remove `orderBy('title').`. It works fine. How should I do? Thank you

Comment: Thank you for all your advices. I solved this issue by: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56614131/firestore-orderby-and-where-conflict

Answer (score 0):

There are two restrictions on using `orderBy()`:

- An `orderBy()` clause also filters for existence of the given fields. The result set will not include documents that do not contain the given fields.
- If you include a filter with a range comparison (<, <=, >, >=), your first ordering must be on the same field

Second seems like not your case, so the only bet is that your queried documents have no field `subtitle`. Have a check if they exist or if there is a typo somewhere.