# Using Where and Order by different fields in Firestore query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore collection named `channels`, and I'd like to get the list of channels based on an array of IDs and order it by the `createdAt` field, this is my function :

```
  const getChannels = () => {
    const q = query(
      collection(db, "channels"),
      where(documentId(), "in", [
        "F0mnR5rNdhwSLPZ57pTP",
        "G8p6TWSopLN4dNHJLH8d",
        "wMWMlJwa3m3lYINNjCLT",
      ]),
      orderBy("createdAt")
    );
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
      snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.data());
      });
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  };
```

But I'm getting this error

`FirebaseError: inequality filter property and first sort order must be the same: __name__ and createdAt`.

It only works if I orderBy `documentId()`.

I'm aware there is a limitation in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) about this, but I'm wondering if there is a workaround for this type of situation.

Also the answer for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56614131/firestore-orderby-and-where-conflict) isn't working anymore I guess.

Comment: add composite_indexes, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#composite_indexes

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The title of your question indicates that you are trying to use `where` and `orderBy` for different fields. But note that you are using `documentId()` in the where condition to filter, which is not a field in the Firestore document.

So if you filter is based on `documentId()`, you can use only `documentId()` in `orderBy()` clause, that also in ascending order because currently Firestore does not support sorting in descending order of `documentId()` which is mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52119324).

Let’s take a look at the following examples -

```
const data=await db.collection("users").where(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(),"in",["104","102","101"]).orderBy(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId()).get();
```

The above will work and sort the documents based on `documentId()` after filtering based on `documentId()`.
But it is not relevant to apply an `orderBy()` clause based on the `documentId()`, because without applying the `orderBy()` clause also yields the same result as, by default, Firestore query gives documents in ascending order of `documentId()`. That means the following also yields the same result -

```
const data=await db.collection("users").where(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(),"in",["104","102","101"]).get();
```

Now Firestore doesn’t support to sort in descending order of `documentId()` which means the following will not work -

```
const data=await db.collection("users").where(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(),"in",["104","102","101"]).orderBy(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(),"desc").get();
```

This will ask to create an index -

```
The query requires an index. You can create it here:
```

But if you go there to create an index it will say -

```
__name__ only indexes are not supported.
```

Now let's come to your query. What you are trying to do is to filter based on `documentId()` and then `orderBy()` based on `createdAt` field which is not possible and it will give the following error-

```
inequality filter property and first sort order must be the same.
```

You may think to use two `orderBy()` clauses, something like this -

```
const data=await db.collection("users").where(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(),"in",["104","102","101"]).orderBy(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId()).orderBy(“createdAt”
).get();
```

Which will not work and give the following error

```
order by clause cannot contain more fields after the key
```

I am not sure of your use case but it’s not a great idea to filter based on `documentId()`. If it is required to filter based on `documentId()`, I would suggest creating a field in the Firestore document which will contain the documentIds and filter based on that.

Now considering the title of the question, yes it is possible to use where() and orderBy() clauses for different fields in Firestore. There are some [limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#limitations) and you need to stick to that -

> If you include a filter with a range comparison (<, <=, >, >=), your first ordering must be on the same field.

```
const data=await db.collection("users").where(“number”,">=", “101”).orderBy(“createdAt”).get();
```

The above query doesn't  work.

```
const data=await db.collection("users").where(“number”,">=", “101”).orderBy(“number”).get();
```

The above query works and you can still use further `orderBy()` on different fields, something like following -

```
const data=await db.collection("users").where(“number”,">=", “101”).orderBy(“number”).orderBy(“createdAt”).get();
```

> You cannot order your query by any field included in an equality (=) or in clause.

```
const data=await db.collection("users").where(“number”,"in",["104","102","101"]).orderBy(“number”).get();
const data=await db.collection("users").where(“number”,"==", “101”).orderBy(“number”).get();
```

The above two don’t work.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, it did help me understand it better. I'd like to know what solution you'll choose to overcome the problem I posted though, selection many documents by any field, it doesn't have to be `documentId()` using `in`, and then orderBy `createdAt` desc. What is a possible solution for this case using Firestore?

Comment: To filter based on `documentId` you can add a field in Firestore which stores the `documentId`. Then you can filter based on the created field and apply `orderBy()` with the field `createdAt`. Please note that you can `orderBy()` with `createdAt` and simultaneously filter by `where()` clause using the `in` operator with any field except `createdAt`.

Comment: I understand, I did try it before but it didn't work that's why I was confused maybe I messed up something. I'm using another unique field named `number` for the query, and now it's as follow : `const q = query(collection(db, "channels"), where("number", "in", ["73462249946615613214", "833913924613465430"]), orderBy("createdAt", "desc"));` and it's working fine after creating the suggested index by Firestore.

Answer (score 1):

Firestore's speed and efficiency comes almost ENTIRELY from it's use of indexes.  Inequalities (INCLUDING `in` and `not-in`) are accomplished by sorting by the index, and using the value as a "cut-off" - thus REQUIRING (whether you want it or not) the `orderby()` to be on the same field as the inequality.

The "answer not working anymore" was never really working in the first place, as the above shows.  If you aren't trying to paginate, do the obvious and "filter" by the document ID's and sort on the client.

BUT...

...more importantly, it is ALMOST NEVER useful nor performant to use documentId's to select from the database, unless you both copy it to a field, AND are looking for a SPECIFIC id.  In almost *all* cases, it would be FAR better to use a query on another field (however you got the list of documentId's in the first place), then orderBy.  Yes, the inequality/orderBy is a limitation, but it's there for a reason.

Going forward, an important design decision is to understand what *questions* you want your data to answer, and design your entire database schema to support those queries - this is the fundamental nature of NoSQL.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I'll be querying using another unique field that I already have in my collection called `number`, but I'll still need to orderBy `createdAt`, how do you suggest I do that if I can't query & order by different fields?

Comment: You misunderstand - you CAN query and orderBy different fields - *as long as you use equality, not INequality*.  It is PERFECTLY valid to have ```.where({field: "number", opStr: "==", value: whatever}).orderby("createdAt")```   What is NOT valid would be ```.where({field: "number, opStr: "<=", value: whatever})``` - BECAUSE of the use of "<="

Comment: Yes, I get it, I meant that I need to use the `in`, something like `where("number", "in", "123456", "546789", "543212"]), orderBy("createdAt")`

Comment: @LeadDreamer Hey, thank you for this comment here, very informative. I want to add a quick question, maybe the answer is obvious but I can't seem to see it. How is using a query on a field better than using a query on documentId? Say I have 2 collections: Family and Chore. Each Family document has a field that is an array of ChoreID, represents all the chore within the family. So what I am doing is get the array, and use it to query for the chores belongs to a family.

Comment: Well, first because documentID's are *not* what you think they are https://stackoverflow.com/a/58104104/2434784 - and you'll also find firebase "arrays" are also not what you think they are: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67962717/2434784 . Almost universally better to use sub-collections over arrays, IM(NS)HO

Answer (score -1):

Problem:The other link that you have shared before perfectly works and the only solutions available is to create an index. However the reason you are  not able to do a where and order with the above example is because you cannot create an index with the document id and createdAt.

**Solution:** To do so add the document id as one of the field say docID in the document then create an index with the fields docID and createdAt. This should be working for you.

**Note:** I have not physically tested this. Will update once I have checked it