# How to loop through Instance of '_MapStream<QuerySnapshotPlatform, QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>'?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
  static List categoryList() {
    final categorySnapshots = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('categories')
        .orderBy('name')
        .snapshots();

    List categories = [];
    categorySnapshots.map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
          print(snapshot.toString());
          categories.add(doc.data()['name']);
        }));

    print(categories);
    return categories;
  }
```

Categories is empty.
How to populate it with the data from snapshots?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `snapshot.data!.docs.map`?

Comment: It says "The getter 'data' isn't defined for the type 'QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>'"

Comment: `snapshots()` will return a stream, so you should use it when you wan't to listen to realtime updates. If you want to make a one-time query, use `get()` instead of `snapshots()` and `await` the result.

Answer (score 0):

Using the below code might help

you can convert the snapshot to Map<String,dynamic> by using the following function:

```
 static Post fromSnap(DocumentSnapshot snap) {
var snapshot = snap.data() as Map<String, dynamic>; 
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I added a new collection called "school", there're two items added inside the document.

```dart
  void getMessagesTest() async{
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await _firestore.collection('school').orderBy('age',descending: true).get();
    final allData = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();
    print(allData);
  }
```

I used my code, and it works. Could you please remove ".where" and try it again?

[image]
[image]

You could chain where and orderBy together. Please see my code below. Reference link => [Using Where and Order by different fields in Firestore query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70148800/using-where-and-order-by-different-fields-in-firestore-query)

```dart
  void getMessagesTest() async{
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await _firestore.collection('school').orderBy('age', descending: true).where('age', isGreaterThan: 17).get();
    final allData = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();
    print(allData);
  }
```